# How can I run a user request in the background?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, cron

I need that when the user clicks a particular button on the screen (which fires an Ajax request w/o server), the server releases the user's screen and continue running in the background service. I'm using PHP and jQuery with ZendFramework. How should I approach this?

Comment: ajax requests are already "background" jobs.

Comment: but i need, continue the execution with free user's screen, without  response wait

Comment: that's what ajax is for. fire a request off in the background of the browser, leaving the user able to continue working on a page.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand your question (the Portuguese version is not more clear than the English one). As far as I understand you want to have your php code continue running while the user can do other stuff.

Normally you don't need to do anything to achieve this, When the ajax call runs in the background, your server will continue processing even if other requests are made. Also it is not the server that controls the user's screen, since that is client side.

If you want to be able to run js while the ajax is running, well jQuery supports synchronous and asynchronous calls but asynchronous is the default, so again you shouldn't do anything special.

Please elaborate your question further and maybe show some code so we can understand and I will update my anwer and clean up the English in your question once I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding php exec in your ajax calling script.

```
exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
```

You have to reroute programs output somewhere too, usually /dev/null